# Binary prediction with data involving starting and ending time

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, decision-tree, prediction

I have a data-set about package delivery, with columns such as time of travel, planned shipping time, actual shipping time, delay and planned delivery time. And on the basis of this, I need to predict if the delivery will be on time or not. The following is the data-set:

[image]

I am planning to use `sklearn`'s `LabelEncoder()` for categorical features and then fit this data to a `DecisionTreeClassifier()`. My question is, should I transform the features containing TIME or just leave it? A time value of `1955` means `19:55` and `735` means `07:35`. I am using python.

Comment: It's not necessary to transform. The time values have an intrinsic order to them (e.g. 19:55 > 7:35). Also Ofer's point would be valid if you're using a model that uses the feature in a least square implementation (e.g. linear regression), etc. DT's just split on values so it wouldn't matter if you're splitting on 1955 or 19:55 in minutes. Also, if you want to test linear regression, you want to normalize your features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the difference between values of `1959` for 19:59 and `2000` for 20:00 is basically just 1 minute, you lose that context by using this kind of data representation. For example, your model will understand the difference between those two examples to be the same as a difference between `1900` and `1941`, which is not at all what you're planning to happen.

I can't prove to you mathematically that this will cause errors in your training model, but it's very bad practice. If possible, I would convert to something else that's more uniform, for example minutes since 00:00 (midnight):

```
def time_converter(time_str):
    hours = int(time_str[:2])
    minutes = int(time_str[2:])
    time_since_midnight = (hours * 60) + minutes
    return time_since_midnight

time_converter('1940') # will return 1180 integer for 1180 minutes since midnight
```

Do that consistently to all times in your data of course, to avoid any misrepresentation

Answer (score 1):

As you have shipment delay column so actual shipment time and planned shipment time is not required.

And you have planned travel time so planned delivery time is not required.

But The delivery may depends on the time of day(ex: morning or afternoon or evening) So you can make few categories out of the actual shipment time and use those for model building.

So, You can't really ignore time columns while building the model.

Comment: Shipment delay could depend on time of day, therefore, planned shipment time could or could not be required, that depends.

Comment: shipment delay is actually subtracting actual shipment time from planned shipment time.

Comment: Agree. But that time difference can vary depending on time of day. For example, it is easy to keep the schedule in the middle of the night, when the traffic is low, but not during working hours, when traffic jams are very often.